# How LinearLayout align in left bottom after Scale?

Tags: android, view, scale

i have `LinearLayout`, i scale `LinearLayout`

```
ll.setScaleX(0.8f);
ll.setScaleY(0.8f);
```

I want to align left botton after Scale. How i can make this?

When i make:

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point mdispSize = new Point();
mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
maxX = mdispSize.x; 
maxY = mdispSize.y;
commonCardContainer.setX(0);
commonCardContainer.setY(maxY - commonCardContainer.getHeight());
```

I have result "after scale" (see picture)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set the pivot point before scale it:

```
yourLayout.setPivotX(0); // Left
yourLayout.setPivotY(yourLayout.getHeight()); // Bottom
```

Comment: i set setPivotX(0) view move left but if i need view move to right what i need set ?

Answer (score 0):

there are second way take one parent Relativelayout to your linearlayout and set align_parentBottom=true and align_parentLeft=true...i hope this will help you. i havent try this...